# SAS Formats and mix missing and nonmissing values in the same range Erros's

Tags: sas

I have one table called ENC:

```
PAYS   | Header |CD2  |VAL1|VAL2| COEF
------ | ------ |-----|----|----|-----
BRE    | MATLAB | 11  |.   |500 |-0,9561
BRE    | MATLAB | 11  |500 |.   |0
BRE    | MATLAB | 2   |.   |550 |-1,2212
BRE    | MATLAB | 2   |550 |.   |0
```

and I would like to create a SAS Format by using this code:

```
data WORK.FMT_ENC(keep=START END FMTNAME LABEL);
    length FMTNAME $32;
    retain FMTNAME ;
    set ENC (rename=(VAL1=start VAL2=end   COEF=label)) end=eof;
    FMTNAME = lowcase(compress('$' !! PAYS !! Header !! put(CD2,2.)!!'_flgperso'));
    /*retain fmtname "test" type "C";*/
    output;
    if eof then
    do;
        hlo = "O";
        label = "Autre";
        output;
    end;
    run;
    proc format library=WORK cntlin=WORK.FMT_ENC;
run;
```

and I get this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot mix missing and nonmissing values in the same range: .-500.
```

Please could you help me?
Missing values are the lowest or greatest values.
Thanks

Comment: What is supposed to happen for these four rows?  What does missing signify - is this supposed to be "lowest possible value" or similar?  And, why does your `cntlin` dataset not match your `data` set name?

Comment: You have overlapping ranges and your fmtname is commented out, you should have more errors.

Comment: Reeza, its the only errors i have.